# Look for an attribute value in a list of object

Tags: python

I've got a list of `User` and I try to return one of them base on `id` attributes.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel,ValidationError
import json

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int

class Data():
    def __init__(self, jsonfile : str) :
        self.users_list= []
        with open(jsonfile) as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        for u in users :
            try :
                self.users_list.append(User(**u))
            except ValidationError as e:
                print(e.json())  
  
    def get_user(self,id : int) -> User :
        if self.users_list.index(id) : # How to search in my list of User for a specific id ?
            return self.users_list.index(id)
        else :
           return None
```

I could go through the whole list of `User` and check theirs `id` attribute, but I was wondering if they were a cleaner way to do it than something like

```py
for u in self.users_list : 
    if u.id == id :
        return u
```

Comment: maybe you can make a dictionary with `id` as key and user as value. If id is in dict you simply returning. Both indexing and checking if id is in dict is O(1) operation

Comment: Right.  Do like a database does -- make an index for those columns you'll access most often.  The index can map a key to a list entry number.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that. That's a good idea :)
Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the fastest search times I would recommend using a dictionary with the key being the id of the user.

I made a python test file to test the different data structures in python to find the fastest solution.

Here are the results from my findings in milliseconds:

List Append Time:  0.8620707350000001

Dict Append Time:  1.2875515819999999

Set Append Time:  1.325187916

List Find User Time:  0.0658235330000001

Dict Find User Time:  2.4221999999962662e-05

Set Find User Time:  0.10515519500000003

As you can see from my testing Dictionaries are magnitudes faster than lists or sets.

```
import time

class Counter:
  _start = float

  def __init__(self):
    self.start_time()

  def start_time(self):
    self._start = time.perf_counter()
    return self._start

  @property
  def time_elapsed(self):
    time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - self._start
    self.start_time()
    return time_elapsed



class User:
  id: int

  def __init__(self, user_id):
    self.id = user_id

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.id == other

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.id + id(self))

user_dict = {}
user_set = set()
users = []


counter = Counter()

for i in range(0, 1000000):
  user = User(i)
  users.append(user)

print('List Append Time: ', counter.time_elapsed)

for i in range(0, 1000000):
  user = User(i)
  user_dict[str(user.id)] = user

print('Dict Append Time: ', counter.time_elapsed)

for i in range(0, 1000000):
  user = User(i)
  user_set.add(user)

print('Set Append Time: ', counter.time_elapsed)


for user in users:
  if user == 500000:
    break

print('List Find User Time: ', counter.time_elapsed)

found_user = user_dict['500000']

print('Dict Find User Time: ', counter.time_elapsed)

for user in user_set:
  if user == 500000:
    break

print('Set Find User Time: ', counter.time_elapsed)
```